# Laragon - pretty url for one app does not work

Tags: php, laravel, apache, laragon

After enabling the auto virtual host I wanted to try pretty url for my current project. Problem is it first showed index of/ of the project and after trying some solutions it now shows "This site cannot be reached!" error. The pretty url feature wotks withother projects.

What I tried:

.restarting laragon and pc

.enabeling nginx

.renaming the project

.clearing something in my apache server

Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

what i do is :

a. open laragon > menu > apache > sites-enabled > **Delete all [auto]**

b. if you are using ur own computer, please set **Open as administrator** to Laragon

c. make sure **auto virtual host** is checked on laragon

d. last, check your host file, **don't forget to un-check 'Read-Only' options**

Comment: Nice. I had the same problem. Now it's solved.

Comment: nice man it worked

Comment: d. "_check your host file_" what do you mean by this, and where to find it?

Answer (score 1):

For me, I need to remove the 'Read-Only' option of `hosts` file in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`. I'm using Windows, obviously.